# Validation not working for Joomla registration form

Tags: validation, joomla1.5, user-registration

I have joomla site with Version 1.5.23.
I am new to joomla and php but in the existing site I am trying to add "Sign up for mailing list" functionality.
For this I have added:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_user&view=register" class="jregister">
Sign up for our Mailing List</a>
```

in my `index.php` page.
Due to above code I got panel on right side of page.
On click of that link one registration form is displaying, on click of register button validations are not working.
But if I enter correct information then I get successful registration message with confirmation email.

Please suggest why validation for name, password, email are not working.
I'm sure this is a really simple error somewhere but its beyond me I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

registration form in joomla is a joomla Component that linked to login module and login form.
you should write validation code "by yourself" for registration form in this path:

```
JOOMLAROOT/component/com_user/views/register/tmpl/default.php
```

Comment: Yes i have login form and all the validations on          JOOMLAROOT/component/com_user/views/register/tmpl/default.php       page. But not getting the error messages or any response from it.

Comment: Maybe your validation code is not working correctly. I have a joomla site and write validation code for both login form and registration form and it work correctly!